# How to override listItem icon tooltip?

Tags: javascript, icons, tooltip, sapui5, listitem

I am trying to change tooltip of icon which is in core: ListItem.

tooltip property of listItem is changing tooltip of whole item which is not what im looking for.

```
<core:ListItem icon="sap-icon://message-error" tooltip="someTooltip" />
```

Comment: There is no individually tooltip for an icon in a list item. Only the whole list item got a tooltip

Comment: As @alexP mentioned, you cant have the tooltip specific for the icon only. As it mentioned `ListItem` refer to a complete item.  You can use the `sap.m.CustomListItem` and have the tooltip specifically for the icon only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you need to extend the `core: ListItem` OR you can use a workaround for your problem using `sap.m.CustomListItem` and specify the icon tooltip.

**View.xml**

```
<List items="{/items}">
  <CustomListItem>
    <HBox>
      <core:Icon size="2rem" width="50px" tooltip="{tooltipInfo}" src="{icon}" />               
      <VBox>
        <Link text="{title}"/>
        <Label text="{type}"/>
      </VBox>
    </HBox>
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

**Controller.js**

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({
  "items": [
     { "tooltipInfo": "Group1", "icon": "sap-icon://hint", "type": "Monitor", "title": "Tiles: a modern UI design pattern for overview & navigation."},
     { "tooltipInfo": "Group2", "icon": "sap-icon://inbox", "number": "89", "title": "Approve Leave Requests", "info": "Overdue", "infoState": "Error" },
     { "tooltipInfo": "Group3", "icon": "sap-icon://email", "type": "Create", "title": "Create Leave Requests", "info": "28 Days Left", "infoState": "Success" },
     { "tooltipInfo": "Group4", "icon": "sap-icon://travel-expense-report", "number": "281", "numberUnit": "euro", "title": "Travel Reimbursement", "info": "1 day ago" },
     { "tooltipInfo": "Group5", "icon": "sap-icon://loan", "number": "2380", "numberUnit": "euro", "title": "My Salary", "info": "8 days ago" },
     { "tooltipInfo": "Group6", "icon": "sap-icon://lab", "number": "1", "numberUnit": "Invention", "title": "Test Lab Reports","info": "8 Days Ago" }]
});
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the tooltip will only show up in the drop down list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
    </script>

    <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="myView.Template"
      xmlns="sap.m" 
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Select>
    <core:ListItem icon="sap-icon://accept" tooltip="someTooltip" />
    </Select>
   </mvc:View>
    </script>
    <script>
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  var oController = Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
  });

  return oController;
});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
});

oView.placeAt('content');
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think, he wants a tooltip only for the icon in the list item. But that's not possible.